# Django | Mostrar imagen recorriendo nombre de archivo de imagen mediante FOR no muestra imagen

Tags: django, django-urls

Al querer mostrar una imagen "static" mostrando el nombre del archivo mediante un for, me devuelve valores que no corresponden a la imagen. ¿Qué hago mal?

Código para mostrar imagen recorriendo con for el nombre del archivo:

```
{% for dispositivo in dispositivos %}
<img src="{% static 'img/dispositivos/{{ dispositivo.imagen_dispositivo }}' %}">
{% endfor %}
```

Código fuente del código creado:

```
<img src="/static/img/dispositivos/%7B%7B%20dispositivo.imagen_dispositivo%20%7D%7D">
```

¿Qué sucede?

Comment: yo entiendo tu caso. `{% for dispositivo in dispositivos %} <img src="{% static 'img/dispositivos/{{ dispositivo.imagen_dispositivo }}' %}"> {% endfor %}` No se si alguien sabrá alguna solución, ya que con esas líneas de código se pretender iterar los nombres de las imágenes para buscarlo en una ruta establecida => 'img/dispositivos/{{ dispositivo.imagen_dispositivo }}' , pero el motor no renderiza esa logica, ayuden porfa. tambien probe con string.format, no funciona por la limitacion de la etieuta <img/>.

Answer (score 0):

Cámbialo por esto.

```
{% for dispositivo in dispositivos %}
<img src="{{ dispositivo.imagen_dispositivo }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Si puedes mostrar el modelo de dispositivos seria mucho mejor, ese ejemplo es para mostrar las imagenes de un ImageField con una fila llamada imagen_dispositivo.

```
class Dispositivos(models.Model):
    imagen_dispositivo = models.ImageField
```

**¿Qué sucede? en tu error**
estas usando la etiqueta **Static**, que es para archivos dentro de tu aplicación. Esta etiqueta no se usa nunca para modelos ni para datos en tu base de datos.  La etiqueta static obtiene los archivos dentro de la carpeta indicada en STATIC_URL

Comment: No estoy en modelo, el código corresponde a template. La ruta de la imagen es "static/images/dispositivos" y el nombre de archivo a mostrar mediante for es por ejemplo imagen1.jpg No me interesa guardar la imagen en el modelo, sólo el nombre de la imagen. Posiblemente esté confundido en el planteamiento. Gracias.

Comment: @julian Usa {% static 'img/dispositivos/imagen1.jpg' %}